# The type initializer for 'LibGit2Sharp.Core.NativeMethods' threw an exception

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio-2017, console-application, libgit2sharp

I am working on a C# console application `(.NET 4.6.1)` and when running its executable I get the following error:

> The type initializer for 'LibGit2Sharp.Core.NativeMethods' threw an
>   exception.

Error description:

> at
>   LibGit2Sharp.Core.NativeMethods.git_repository_open(git_repository*&
>   repository, FilePath path)
>   at LibGit2Sharp.Core.Proxy.git_repository_open(String path)
>   at LibGit2Sharp.Repository..ctor(String path, RepositoryOptions options,
>   RepositoryRequiredParameter requiredParameter)
>   at LibGit2Sharp.Repository..ctor(String path)
>   at MyProj.MyClass.GetMaxBranchVersion(String
>   repoPath)

Inner exception:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 
>   'System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation, Version=0.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. File name:
>   'System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation, Version=0.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'    at
>   LibGit2Sharp.Core.Platform.get_OperatingSystem()    at
>   LibGit2Sharp.Core.NativeMethods..cctor()

Now, the project's code works fine when debugging it or just running it with Visual Studio - the error comes up when trying to run it as an executable. 
The issue is not really with the *GetMaxBranchVersion* method itself, because I tried not calling it at all and this only caused the error to come up anyway, when running the next method.

I tried adding the following configuration items to the .csproj file as per [this answer](https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/issues/697) but unfortunately, it did not solve my problem:

```
<PropertyGroup>
..
<AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
<GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>true</GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>
..
</PropertyGroup>
```

What could be the possible reason?

*I understand the information provided might not be a lot, but I can provide additional details if needed.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to solve my issue doing the following:

1. Changed the `Target Framework` for the project to `.NET 4.7`
2. Copied the `System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.dll` inside the folder where I was trying to run the executable from

At this point I got another error:

> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'git2-6311e88': The
>   specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x8007007E)    at LibGit2Sharp.Core.NativeMethods.git_libgit2_init()
>   at LibGit2Sharp.Core.NativeMethods.LoadNativeLibrary()    at
>   LibGit2Sharp.Core.NativeMethods..cctor()

Thanks to [this answer](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues/39) I was able to overcome this issue by 
copying also the **`git2-6311e88.dll`** (the x86 version was needed in my case, which is normally located on your `bin/debug` or `bin/release` folder, under `lib/os-version`, in my case `lib/win32`)

And voilà! It works! Good luck to anyone struggling with the same issue.